# "render_placeholder" not showing up in djangoCMS template

Tags: python, django, placeholder, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I have followed the instructions on the following site in order to render a placeholder field from a model, but I didn't manage.

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/placeholders.html

This is my model.

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.utils import timezone
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField

class HomePage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    my_placeholder = PlaceholderField('placeholder_name')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
       db_table = "home_page_content"
       verbose_name = 'Home Page Content'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Home Page Content'
```

This is my view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.models.home_page import HomePage

def HomePageContent(request):

   object = HomePage.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'object': object})
```

This is how I render the placeholder in the template.

```
    {% load cms_tags %}

    {% for obj in object %}
      {% render_placeholder obj.my_placeholder "640" %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And nothing shows up.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I also facing this issue, if you fixed this issue, then please help me... I am facing issue like I get message: double click to edit (when hover on content)
When I double click on content.. A popup is open with body content but not able to edit that content

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the PlaceholderAdminMixin on the admin I think. You did not specify the admin so I am not sure.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdminMixin

class HomePageAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```